# PKCS11 ECDSA parameters in go module pkcs11

Tags: go, pkcs#11, elliptic-curve, ecdsa, hsm

I would like to know how to pass the correct argument values for ECDSA template using go module [miekg/pkcs11](https://github.com/miekg/pkcs11): this is so far what i got:

```
    privateKeyTemplate := []*pkcs11.Attribute{
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_TOKEN, tokenPersistent),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_ECDSA_PARAMS, []byte{{/*how to use secp256k1?*/}), 
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_SIGN, true),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_LABEL, label),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_SENSITIVE, true),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_EXTRACTABLE, true),
    }
```

Can someone please help me with this?

thanks

**EDIT:**

the byte array provided by Alexander is correct, however please note that my original question was also misleading. One **SHOULD NOT** put the ECDSA_PARAMS in the private key template, but ONLY on the public key template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this line (3189) in [OpenSC](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/blob/2b78374e37b44e06a9f9ca45fc9ccf72081a27f6/src/tools/pkcs11-tool.c#L3184-L3207) project:

```
FILL_ATTR(privkey_templ[n_privkey_attr], CKA_EC_PARAMS, gost.param_oid.value, gost.param_oid.len);
```

and this one (3199):

```
FILL_ATTR(privkey_templ[n_privkey_attr], CKA_GOSTR3410_PARAMS, gost.param_oid.value, gost.param_oid.len);
```

Using my experience with GOST keys I suggest that here must be an encoded OID. In your case it can look like this:

```
[]byte{ 06, 04, 01, 02, 03, 04 }
```